# Arrow code not working

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, tikz-arrows

I can't figure out the code to put labels with arrows on my plot, and can't seem to find a manual for it. I just want a label 'text' to be positioned at one point, with an arrow coming from the right side and pointing to some other point. My current code below (which doesn't quite work).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5,] {Images/test}
    node at (30pt,30pt) {text} [->] (50pt,50pt);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, please don't change `node at` to `\node`. My actual code has a lot of labels in the `node at` form and I don't want to rewrite them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply say `[->]` to draw the arrow. You need to, somehow create the path... You can either say

```
node (a) at (30pt,30pt) {text};
\draw[->] (a) -- (50pt,50pt);
```

Where the `\draw` command creates the path. Or, much simpler, use the `edge` operation

```
node at (30pt,30pt) edge[->] (50pt,50pt);
```

The `edge` operation suspends the current path construcion and creates a new path, in that way, the `edge` can be completely different from the actual path it was built on.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=5,] {example-image}
    node at (30pt,30pt) {text} edge[->] (50pt,50pt);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### EDIT:

The OP wants to have the `edge` coming from the `north west` anchor of the node. One way to do that is to explcitly say so, by naming the node:

```
node (a) at (30pt,30pt) {text} (a.north east) edge[->] (50pt,50pt);
```

But, since the OP wants a way that does not require naming the node, another logic can be used. Instead of creating the `node` and placing an `edge` to connect it to something, we can reverse the logic: create an `edge` connecting two coordinates and placing a `node` on the `edge`'s start.

```
(30pt,30pt) edge[->] node[at start,anchor=north west]{text} (50pt,50pt);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was after. How do I place the start of the arrow on the centre right, rather than top right of the text?

Comment: Well, the nodes are not like coordinates, they have several anchors (the anchors, though, are like coordinates). When you have a node named `a` and you say `(a) edge[->] (1,1)` you're actually saying `(a.center) edge[->] (1,1)` . So, you need to change that anchor, explicitly, like `(a.north west) edge[->] (1,1)`.

Comment: If the code is in the form `node at (30pt,30pt) {text} edge[->] (50pt,50pt);` how would it change?

Comment: I can't find a manual that explains how to do any of this. I don't know what anchors are or how to use them, or what the syntax is.

Comment: Then I wonder how you got so far! You are using [PGFPlots](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), but that is based on [Ti*k*Z/PGF](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), the links will lead you to their manuals, the second one, is definetly what you're looking for. As for the code: `node (A) at (30pt,30pt) {text} (A.north west) edge[->] (50pt,50pt);` should work.

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to name the node? Is there a way to do the exact same thing without naming it?

Comment: It's not *necessary* to name the node to do this, *in every ocasion*. To keep the `node at` syntax, though, it's absolutely necessary (the explanation to that lies in my previous comment). If you do this another way, then naming the node can be optional. I'll provide a way in the answer because it doesn't fit in a comment.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to change the `node at`, but it's either that, or naming the node. I see no other option (and I'm afraid *there is* no other option)... `:/`

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I've opted for naming the node. My concern was just that using names could increase the chance of errors as I could accidentally give multiple nodes with arrows the same name, but I've tested this and surprisingly it doesn't kick up a fuss, and renders everything correctly. Naturally I'll try to avoid this though. Tikz seems pretty bombproof, but I won't try to push it too far.

Comment: Actually you can use only one name for all nodes, there's no issue there. The nodes' names are stored in macros so, they're renewed. The problem is, of course, once you renew a command the previous one is unavailable, but that's only a problem if you want to call upon this node afterwards... :)

Comment: Thanks for that helpful info. I couldn't really find those sort of details in the manual. It's good to know how it's working in the background so I know under what conditions I will or won't have errors or undesired behaviour. Since I don't yet have any need to call upon the node again, this doesn't look like it'll be an issue.